# Grouping Extjs Form Fields in JSON output

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1

I have the following Form Structure:

```
| id <hidden field> 
\
 |- Personal Details
 \
 | Name
 | Surname
```

When I use the form.getFormValues() I get the following JSON output:

```
id:<idValue>,
name:<nameValue>,
surname:<surNameValue>
```

What I'd like to get as output is as follows:

```
id:<idValue>,
personalDetails {name:<nameValue>, surname:<surNameValue>}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in ExtJS?

I've looked into FieldContainer & FieldSets but can't seem to get the result I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not, the form is not aware of any hierarchy of fields, calling `getValues()` returns plain object with name/value pairs.

Comment: But for example (here: http://jsfiddle.net/vzUdn/103/) you can know this for the ChecboxGroup, is there no such component for Textfields?

Comment: Checkboxgroup is special in that that it doesn't have a single value as it may contain many checkboxes. Therefore, the value is an array - checkboxes have same names. Nothing like that for other fields.